# How to select jq items where length of key value exceeds a number

Tags: json, select, jq

I have this JSON input to JQjq

```json
{
  "names": [{
    "name": "John Smith"
  },{
    "name": "Jane Doe"
  },{
    "name": "Jackson Longfellow"
  }]
}
```

I'd like to use jq to select all the items where the length of the name is > 10 characters.  This means the output would be:

```json
{
  "names": [{
    "name": "Jackson Longfellow"
  }]
}
```

The `length` filter only seems to count items in an array.  Is there some other built-in filter to use for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Update `|=` the `names` array by `select`ing only those items that match. `length` applied to a string will output its length counting Unicode codepoints.

```sh
jq '.names |= map(select(.name | length > 10))'
```

```json
{
  "names": [
    {
      "name": "Jackson Longfellow"
    }
  ]
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/N52Ul4xAr1)

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you.